# installing software repository error message

Tags: linux, linux-distributions

I am trying to install Team Viewer locally from USB drive. I downloaded it from the Web (`teamviewer_linux.rpm`).

I am getting following error message:

```
[Errno 14] Could not open/read file:///mnt/usb/repodata/repomd.xml

Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: localbase. Please verify its path and try again
```

I have created a new repo:

```
[localbase]
name=teamviewer
baseurl=file:///mnt/usb
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
```

Thanks in advance.

I appreciate your quick response.

Answer (score 0):

you have no repo data on the usb use createrepo pkg OR run sudo yum/dnf  install /mnt/usb/teamviewer_linux.rpm AFTER removing the local repo which is pointing at thin air according to that paste.